Error while loading roles. Error: Invalid Domain Name
I'm unable to view the profile of some of the users from secondary userstore(LDAP) when logged in as on carbon as admin in WSO2 Identity Server. I get the following while trying to load the profile:
user profile error image
Verison: 5.11.0
Here is the full error log that gets printed while this issue occurs:
TID: [-1234] [] [2024-09-23 12:17:03,303] [d5c0c732-6666-497c-9fee-71959b778098] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserRealmProxy} - org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Invalid Domain Name TID: [-1234] [] [2024-09-23 12:17:03,305] [d5c0c732-6666-497c-9fee-71959b778098] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient} - Invalid Domain Name org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminUserAdminException: UserAdminUserAdminException at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at java.base/
I restarted the instance thinking that the LDAP will sync all the users. I also deleted and re-added the userstore and I was not successful.
